# How to concat carriage return char with a string in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am creating an autotest of transformation of one xml file into another. I am using xpath for that.
There are two fields in input file A and B. The result is the following

```
<Address>A
B</Address>
```

So there is a carrige return char (\n) is added between A and B. But if write and xpath like

```
concat(//Address1,"\n",//Address2)
```

I get wrong result: A\nB.

I tried concatination with the following chars: "\n", "&#13;", "&#10;", "&\amp;crlf"

How can I concat strings with carriage return char?

Comment: what is the platform/xpath engine?

Comment: I am using soapUI for testing and it executes these xpath

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this in one step with `concat()` function, but you can get carriage return by adding `<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>` between output of Address1 and Address2, something like:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//Address1, '')" />
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//Address2, '')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether you are on a Windows or Unix like platform. On Windows a line end is CRLF, whereas on Unix it is just LF.

CR is `&#xD` while LF is `&#xA`.

So, on Windows platforms:

```
concat(//Address1, "&#xD;&#xA;", //Address2)
```

Or on Unix like platforms:

```
concat(//Address1, "&#xA;", //Address2)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in xsl document select attribute. need `codepoints-to-string(10)`